# Angular 2 component not updated after external librairie call

Tags: javascript, angular, ethereum

I'm currently trying to build an application composed of an Angular2 IHM and a blockchain IHM (with EthereumJS).
I've got almost everything working except for the angular 2 part.
I have a component which should display an account balance on the blockchain account.
To get this balance, I have to make a call to a blockchain back-end thought Ethereum JS API, web3.

After this information has been retrieved, I want to update my component with the balance data.
Unfortunately this is not working.

I'm aware of the zone.js issue when executing code not handled by Angular.
So far, I've tried several things to fix this issue as you can see in this code sample :

**My component :**

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, EventEmitter, Input, Output, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import template from './wallet.template.html';
import MonTierce from "../../../../../contracts/MonTierce.sol";
import { MonTierceService } from '../../services/montierce/monTierce.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'wallet',
  template: template,
  styleUrls: ['css/wallet.css']
})
export class WalletComponent {

  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder, changeDetect: ChangeDetectorRef, serviceTierce: MonTierceService, ngZone: NgZone, ref: ApplicationRef) {
      this.currentBalance = 0;
      this.currentAddress = "No address found";

      this.currentAddress = serviceTierce.getDefaultAddress();

      var accountInterval = setInterval(function () {
        console.log("interval start");
        if (web3.eth.accounts[0] !== this.currentAddress) {
          console.log("update");
          this.currentAddress = web3.eth.accounts[0];
          changeDetect.detectChanges();
          ngZone.run(() => {
            serviceTierce.getBalance(this.currentAddress).subscribe(data => {
              console.log(data);
              this.currentBalance = web3.fromWei(data, 'ether');
              console.log(this.currentBalance);
              changeDetect.detectChanges();
              ref.tick();
            });

          });

        }
      }, 1000);
  }

}
```

https://github.com/benjaminfontaine/codelab-ethereum/blob/master/horse-bet/client/app/core/components/wallet/wallet.component.js

In this component, I'm trying to update the account balance every second, but the balance stays 0 even thought the log are showing that the balance has been successfully retrieved.

**My service :**

```
import { Injectable, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import MonTierce from "../../../../../contracts/MonTierce.sol";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MonTierceService {

  constructor(ngZone: NgZone) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    MonTierce.setProvider(window.web3.currentProvider);
    var contratTierce = MonTierce.deployed();
    this._contratTierce = contratTierce;
    this._ngZone = ngZone;
  }

  getBalance(address) {
    return new Observable(obs => {
      this._ngZone.run(() => {
        web3.eth.getBalance(address, (error, result) => {
          if(!error){
            obs.next(result.toNumber());
          } else {
            obs.next(error);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }

  getDefaultAddress(){
    return web3.eth.defaultAccount;
  }

  getContractAddress(){
    return this._contratTierce.address;
  }
}
```

https://github.com/benjaminfontaine/codelab-ethereum/blob/master/horse-bet/client/app/core/services/montierce/monTierce.service.js

**My template :**

```
<div [hidden]="!errorMessage" style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold; background-color: red; padding: 3px 10px;">{{errorMessage}}</div>

<div id="panneauControle">
  <div id="wallet">
    <h3> Wallet </h3>
    <p id="activeAccount"><span>Your current address:</span> {{currentAddress}}</p>
    <p><span>Your balance :</span> {{currentBalance}} Ethers</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code might seems a little strange as it's ES6 with some decorators to make it look like typescript.
Here I tried to run the web3 call into ngZone to trigger an applicationRef.tick() at the end of the call.
I also called manually changeRef.detectChange after the call.
Finally in desperation, I also added an ApplicationRef.tick().

Nothing is working my balance gets never updated.

Could you point me to the obvious mistake I made in this code ?

I will gladly take any hint you can give me.

Kind regards.

Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

Late and not sure but did you try to replace:

```
var accountInterval = setInterval(function () { /*...*/ }, 1000)
```

with:

```
var accountInterval = setInterval(() => { /*...*/ }, 1000)
```

Looks like this does not refers to the context of your component here as using the function keyword creates a new scope.